# Assigning variables from dataframe (or spreadsheet) in python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Let's say I have the following dataframe, or spreadsheet:

```
First Name | Last Name   | DOB

Goku           Saiyan      01/01/1950

Vegetta     Super Saiyan   05/04/1981

Freezer      Not Saiyan    07/25/1975
```

I want to do something with python where I could iterate through every row and assign the value of First Name, Last Name and DOB into variables, so I could do something such as:

```
for value in df_rows:
     print(first_name, last_name, dob)
```

And get those values into variables per each row of data in the dataframe or in the spreadsheet.

I've read that it's not good to iterate through the rows with Pandas even though it seems like the easier way to approach this.

With openpyxl, I managed to print and get the `cell.value` of every cell but this also includes all of the empty ones, which messes up the workflow of the loop that I want to use.

If anybody else knows a better way to approach this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want a dataframe variable with all three columns together? `'Goku Saiyan 01/01/1950'`

Comment: No, sorry  if it wasn't clear. I want to have a variable per each value from each row and column, like `first_name = Goku` `last_name = Saiyan` `dob = 01/01/1950`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know that it is not recommended to iterate rows of a pandas data frame, but since you mentioned it, I wanted to test it.

I recreated your data frame with the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "first" : ["Goku", "Vegetta", "Freezer"],
    "last" : ["Saiyan", "Super Saiyan", "Not Saiyan"],
    "DOB" : [pd.to_datetime("01/01/1950"), pd.to_datetime("05/04/1981"), pd.to_datetime("07/25/1975")]
})
```

I then created two methods:

```
def iterate_df(df):
  for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    first = df.loc[i, "first"]
    last = df.loc[i, "last"]
    DOB = df.loc[i, "DOB"]

def iterate_array(df):
  firsts = df["first"]
  lasts = df["last"]
  DOBs = df["DOB"]
  for first, last, dob in zip(firsts, lasts, DOBs):
    pass
```

Then I timed the methods the following way:

```
import time
start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
  iterate_df(df)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
>>> 1.0347726345062256

import time
start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
  iterate_array(df)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
0.32233428955078125
```

This is really interesting as I did not know about the row iteration issue. However, one can see that a superior way in assigning variables is with the second method.

Comment: Well this is this definitely a thorough answer, I'll try it and come back to mark it as correct if it works as expected, thank you very much